# Ruby on Rails: Accept nested attributes for parent rather than child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app `Users` can have many `People` which in turn can (but don't have to) belong to `Organisations`.

In short, this:

```
Users --< People >-- Organisations
```

Now, it would be nice to be able to create new organisations from within a people view somehow. It tried this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :organisation_attributes

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organisation

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisation

end
```

But it's not working because Organisation is not a child of Person.

Is there another way to realise this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see that `Person` is actually a child of `Organisation` and its possible to make nested form for parent model also. And you are already using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Im assuming that you want to show a `Organisation` form for a already saved `person`. Then

In your `PeopleController#show` method build the organisation

```
@person.build_organisation
```

And in `people/show.html.erb`

```
form_for(@person) do |f|
    f.fields_for(:organisation) do |fo|
        # show the fields of organisation here.
    end
end
```

It should work.

**Update:**

I tried something similar and it worked :) Ive made a gist including the snippets.
Please follow the link **https://gist.github.com/3841507** to see it working.

Comment: Please let me know if it works, meanwhile im trying to create a similar scenario in my machine... nice question btw.

Comment: Thanks Samiron! Looks really nice. I need a couple of days to study that code though, because I am still new to Rails.

Comment: sure let me know about any confusion.